# i am unable to press enter key in CYPRESS after double click and type

Tags: cypress

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(function() {      

 
  $(".dblclick").editable("<?php print $url ?>save_jeditable.php", { 
      indicator : "<img src='images/loading.gif'>",
      tooltip   : "Doubleclick to edit...",
      event     : "dblclick",
      style  : "inherit"
  });
  
  
});
</script>
```

html

```
<td id="rec">
<b class="dblclick_dailycapacity" style="display:inline;" id="23_27" title="Doubleclick to edit...">1</b>
</td>
```

This field work like first user double click on it and then type the value after that press enter but i am unable to do this in cypress automation.
Automation code///

```
cy.get('#rec').dblclick()
 cy.get('#23_27').type('12')
 cy.get('#r23_27').type('{enter}').trigger('input')
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: NO i am not Getting any Error, but functionality not preform Properly, means Query is not running after pressing Enter